# Java необходимо в TextView найти повторяющиеся слова

Tags: java, android, textview

Необходимо в TextView найти повторяющиеся слова и указать сколько повторений и желательно вывести в список чтобы каждое слово было как отдельный item чтобы с ним в дальнейшем можно было взаимодейвствовать. Мне было хотя бы алгоритм вывести слови из Textview. Вот что у меня имеется.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view) {


            String myTxt = txtShow.toString().replaceAll("[-.?!)(,:]", "");


            Map<String, Integer> unique = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
            for (String string : myTxt.split("\n")) {
                if(unique.get(string) == null)
                    unique.put(string, 1);
                else
                    unique.put(string, unique.get(string) + 1);
            }
            String uniqueString = join(unique.keySet(), ", ");
            uniqueString.split(". ");
            List<Integer> value = new ArrayList<Integer>(unique.values());

            txt.setText(uniqueString.toString() + value.toString());


        }

        });

/*});
*/
}

public static String join(Collection<String> s, String delimiter) {

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    Iterator<String> iter = s.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        buffer.append(iter.next());
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            buffer.append(delimiter);
        }
    }
    return buffer.toString();

}
```

Comment: У меня если в этой строке for (String string : myTxt.split("\n")) Если заменить на for (String string : "s, s, 3, 3, te, te".replaceAll("[-.?!)(,:]", "").split("\n")) тогда все будет показывать отлично сколько каких элементов, но мне нужно из TextView брать текст.

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка "править" - дополнительную информацию добавляйте в сам вопрос через правку, так людям будет проще понять вашу проблему. Поясните что не так с вашим кодом - по сути два варианта из комментария отличаются только тем, что в первом строка берётся из `TextView`. В остальном код одинаковый.